# R make new variable based on existing Date variable if condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a Dataframe with a date column and an outcome column (1 or 0):

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=100,ncol = 2))
colnames(df) <- c("date_1", "var")
df$date_1 <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 100)
df$var <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.2)
```

I want to make a new variable (preferably using mutate/dplyr) called "date_2" that assigns the date from the "date_1" variable but only if var==1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use case_when from dplyr

```
df %>%
   mutate(date_2 = case_when(var == 1 ~ date))
```

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html